# How to Handle Radio button validation and input in JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx-8

Using JavaFX 8 with FXML.

I have 2 sets of Radio Buttons; Set 1: `A, B, C, D` Set 2: `X, Y`
What I am looking for is

1. Make sure user checks one Radio button from each set before hitting submit, and prompt the user if they didn't.
2. Based on the selection, I will write certain data to an array.

For example, for combination `A` and `Y` selection, write " some text " to `AYcombo` array. For combination `B` and `Y` write "some text" to `BYCombo` array. And so forth.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by using bindings and properties. A ToggleGroup defines the selected toggle as a property (selectedToggleProperty) and you can create a BooleanBinding based on this properties:

```
BooleanBinding binding = groupA.selectedToggleProperty().isNotNull().and(groupB.selectedToggleProperty().isNotNull());
```

Now you can bind the disable property of the button to this binding:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(binding.not());
```

To define the data you can add a listener to the binding (that will be called whenever anything in the binding has changed):

```
binding.addListener(e -> {
    if(binding.getValue()) {
        // calculate and set data
    }
})
```